# How do I display an answer on a separate html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an input that has three possible fortunes depending on the number.

Fortune 1. "You will have a great day."

Fortune 2."Your day is bound by misfortune."

Fortune 3."Today is neither good or bad."

I want to display one of these answers depending on what the user chooses on a separate html page after they hit send.

How would I accomplish this using javascript?

code:

```
  <form>
<label style="color:black ;" for="selectFortune">
   <select  id="selectFortune" >
   <option value="Choice" style="color:black;">Please Pick Between 1 and 3 for your fortune</option>
   <option value="Fortune 1" style="color:black;">1</option>
   <option value="Fortune 2" style="color:black;">2</option>
   <option value="Fortune 3">3</option>
   </select>
</label>

<label for="button">
     <button type="submit" value="submit" id="sLeadSubmit" class="button-green open" data-zcom-event="studios_lead_submit" data-has-zcom-event-handler="1">Send</button>
</label>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add data-url="X" in every option

```
<option value="Fortune 2" style="color:black;" data-url="page1.html">2</option>
```

and run some method on click with

```
<button onclick="onButtonClicked()" type="submit" value="submit" id="sLeadSubmit" class="button-green open" data-zcom-event="studios_lead_submit" data-has-zcom-event-handler="1">Send</button>
```

in `onButtonClicked()` method you can use `window.location.replace()` and make use of `data-url` attribute values
so it would require something like this in the end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onButtonClicked(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // do not send the form
  let select = document.getElementById('selectFortune');
  let url = select.selectedOptions[0].data('url'); // get attribute data-url value
  window.location.replace(url); // go there
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To open new window within click event method you can use :

```
var newTab = window.open("");
```

This will open new tab in browser window 
then to write quotes within this window you can use :

```
newTab.document.write("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get this done using [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp):

- set cookie on submit
- get cookie on seperate page

> Note: the given example below **will not work on stackoverflow**, because we are not allowed to set cookies here.

```js
// to set cookie on submit

function setselection(){
  var project = document.getElementById('selectProject').value;
  document.cookie = 'selectedProject=' + project;
}

// to get cookie on seperate page

function getselection(){
  var name = 'selectedProject=';
  var x = document.cookie.split(';');
  var i = 0, c = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    c = x[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(selectedProject) === 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  } return '';
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="setselection();"><!-- trigger function on submit -->
  <label style="color:black ;" for="selectProject">
    <select class="form-control center-block selectArea formStyle formInput " id="selectProject" name="phone">
    <option value="Web application" style="color:black;">Please Pick Between 1 and 3 for your fortune</option>
    <option value="Fortune 1" style="color:black;">1</option>
    <option value="Fortune 2" style="color:black;">2</option>
    <option value="Fortune 3">3</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <label for="button">
     <button type="submit" value="submit" id="sLeadSubmit" class="button-green open" data-zcom-event="studios_lead_submit" data-ha zcom-event-handler="1">Send</button>
  </label>
</form>
```

> to lean more about cookies take a look at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

On submit event of the form You can use open() method of window and pass the data to show the answers.

```
let formEle = document.getElementById('<your-form-id>');
formEle.addEventListener("submit", onFormSubmit, false);

function onFormSubmit() {
   let newWindow = window.open('<your-other-page-url>');

   let formEle = document.getElementById('<your-form-id>');
   let data = new FormData(formEle);
   newWindow.formData = data;
}
```

then, you can use the formData in another page to read the form data.

Comment: Ok so I tried this and was able to get to the second page, but now how do I display the data that was submitted from the first page on to the second page?

Comment: Right now I just get an empty page when I click submit. But at least it loads the page.

Comment: you can read window.formData in new window and show the details based on your requirement. You need to add 'name' attribute for form controls.